# Sometimes you get unlucky with an evolution? My Vaporeon is so weak, I should just evolve a new one?

Tags: pokemon-go

I hear that *Vaporeon* is a really popular Pokemon. But, mine is very weak at attacking:

> water gun = 6
>   water pulse = 35

On the other hand, my *Flareon*:

> ember = 10
>   heat wave = 80

So, I just got unlucky with the *Eevee* --> *Vaporeon* evolution, right?
My choice is to fight with a *Vaporeon* that has weak fighting skills, or evolve a new one (and hope for the best)?
*Powering-up* will only change HP and CP? My attacks are stuck at 6 and 35?

Comment: Damage for each attack is fixed, and Niantic heavily nerfed Vaporeon last patch

Comment: Your Flareon is actually the real disappointment. Ember deals only 9.5 damage per second and contributes 6.7 energy per second. Heat Wave deals 21.1 damage per second but uses 26.3 energy per second. Assuming *perfect* play, your Flareon's moves actually only deal an average of 11.85 damage per second... Vaporeon's Water Gun, on the other hand, deals 12. The numbers go back slightly in Flareon's favor with base energy charge and his higher attack stat, but Vaporeon should have almost *twice as much HP!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tl;dr**: It's all up to you, but don't judge the strength of the skill by it's Attack power alone. Water Pulse is weak but quick to charge, the best skill (Hydro Pump) requires you to be a better player to use.

---

On viewing [Vaporeon](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/vaporeon.html)'s skills, Water Pulse is weaker on use, but have more uses out of it compared to it's other abilities:

The following information is from here: http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/vaporeon.html

```
Vaporeon Moves                      
Vaporeon Fast Moves:        Vaporeon Charge Moves:      
Water Gun                      Aqua Tail    Hydro Pump  Water Pulse 


Power:  6             Power:    45          90          35  
Cooldown:   0.5 sec   Cooldown: 2.35 sec    3.8 sec     3.3 sec 
Energy: 7             Energy:   -50         -100        -25 
DPS:    12.0          DPS:      19.1        23.7        10.6
```

What's clear here is that while it's two other moves are higher in power, their charge requirements means that you'll need to survive longer before they can be used.  The DPS on the bottom shows that it's more efficient to use the stronger attacks, but that's still under the assumption you're able to get that charge going constantly.  The real DPS per attack is going to be much lower in real world settings as you (as a player) will miss attack opportunities/get hit often.

In theory, you'll want to get another Eevee and hope that your next Vaporeon get Hydro Pump to get the best move-set possible. for now though, Water Pulse is good since you'll get to practice using Pokemon skills more often.

Comment: sigh... I guess it's like the birth lottery. You can't control the attributes of your kids. You get what you get and try to make the best of it. If I were to evolve another, it might be just as weak and so a total waste of resources...

Comment: @konishiki When you start getting interested in upgrading Pokemon, Stardust is actually at a far greater premium than candy, for all but the rarest monsters. Plus, every evolution you invoke grants you 500xp. Evolving further Eevee to look for a Vaporeon you like more is not a waste at all.

Comment: By "better player", do you mean tap quickly and hold as soon as you fill the energy bar?